# Ubuntu 23.04 GUI won't allow LDAP Users to log in, CLI LDAP Works

Tags: login, gui, ldap, client, openldap

Can someone help me to configure Open LDAP clients to log into Ubuntu 23.04 workstation via GUI, so far i can access and log in to the LDAP via CLI i have read a lot of articles regarding the configuration but don't work.
Can someone provide steps by steps - thank you

Comment: Please edit your questions and add what you already tried but didn't work.